# What does 以 mean in 也提供了低层级的控制功能以尽可能提高灵活性和性能?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> TensorFlow 既提供了高层级的 API 以便让您轻松构建和训练您的模型，也提供了低层级的控制功能**以**尽可能提高灵活性和性能。

(Source: [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org))

What does the 以 mean in this context?

The whole sentence would mean:

> TensorFlow already offers the high-level API for you to constitute and train your model, and also offers the lower-level API to control the function and ...?

尽可能 means "as ... ao possible", but I don't understand what the 以 mean in this context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally speaking, you could translate 以 into "so that""in order to" or some other words that introduces the goal or objective of something.

P.S. It seems that this sentence is obtained from direct translation [i.e. word-by-word] with minor modification according to grammar. Usually the structure of these translated Mandarin sentences is fairly close to the that of the original English, so you could try to check each word one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

You have 以便 and 以。 Both mean pretty much the same  'in order to, so that, so as to'.

Tensor Flow既提供了高层级的 API 以便让您轻松构建和训练您的模型，

也提供了低层级的控制功能以尽可能提高灵活性和性能。
(The API) also provides low-level control capability in order to maximise flexibility and performance.

既提供了.... 以便 .... 也提供了....以....